# SQL order by count case

Tags: mysql, count, sql-order-by, case

I am trying to display the first_name, last_name and state of the each president in descending order by state.  However, if multiple presidents come from the same state, I need to display them in order by last name.

I am trying to do this using a `CASE`, but I am new to SQL and not very familiar with how to use the `WHEN`/`THEN` and `ORDER BY` together. Could anyone please point me in the right direction?

I am trying to do something like this:

```
SELECT first_name, last_name, state,
case
    when COUNT(state)>1 then ORDER BY last_name
    else ORDER BY state end 
from president;
```

I have also tried to move the `CASE` clause after the `FROM` statement and use it with `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY` but I have had no luck trying to get the result I need with all the combinations I have tried.

Could anyone tell me if I'm on the right track or if there is a simpler way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Select first_name, last_name,state 
From president 
OrderBy state asc, last_name asc;
```

Comment: worked like a charm, thank you for the quick response and easy solution!